# Azure devops extension SDK - define is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure-devops

I'm trying to develop an extension for Azure DevOps. But whenever I try to use the SDK it pop  an error in the console :

> `Uncaught TypeError: define is not a function`

I've tried to manually add `requestjs`/`requirejs` but it still doesn't work

here is the little code that I use

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!-- <script src="./WorkItemFormPage.tsx" type="module"></script> -->
    <script type="module">
      import * as SDK from "azure-devops-extension-sdk";

      SDK.init();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you need more details about the code, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the problem seems to be with the reference to the script.

[Import the SDK within your extension project](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample):

1. Add azure-devops-extension-sdk to the list of dependencies in your package.json
2. Add import * as SDK from "azure-devops-extension-sdk" to your TypeScript code

You can also refer to the [azure-devops-extension-sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample) repository as a working reference.